# javascript Function not running..erorring out TypeError: winParent is null (winParent.bCleanHtml = false;) on console

Tags: javascript

```
function doModalMFormSubmit_win0(form, name) {
    if (name.indexOf("#ICCancel") != -1) {
       winParent.bCleanHtml = false;
       winParent.loader = null;
       winParent.document.win0.ICStateNum.value = document.win0.ICStateNum.value;
       winParent.aAction_win0(winParent.document.win0, '#ICCancel');
       window.winParent.modWin = null;
       closeModal(window.modalID);
       return;
```

This is the function that is getting error out. console error shows below.
TypeError: winParent is null
winParent.bCleanHtml = false;

Comment: This is the function that runs when cancel is clicked when a popup shows up.

Comment: Where is `winParent` defined? What value it contains?

Comment: If `winParent` doesn't initialized or defined any where globally then place the following line at the start of function:  `var winParent = {}` or `var winParent = Object()`